# Android java Ble, can't stop advertising

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

i've started an advertise and tried calling stop advertiser later but the advertise just won't stop (it just keeps sending its advert even though)

```
advertiser = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();

advSettings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
        .setAdvertiseMode( AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY )
        .setTxPowerLevel( AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH )
        .setConnectable(false)
        .setTimeout(0)
        .build();

AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
        .setIncludeDeviceName( true )
        .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false)
        .addServiceUuid(serviceId)
        .build();

AdvertiseData response = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
        .setIncludeDeviceName( false )
        .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false)
        .addServiceData(serviceId, packet )
        .build();


advertiser.startAdvertising(advSettings, data, response, new AdvertiseCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
        super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
        Log.d(TAG, "Packet was successfully sent");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
        super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
        Log.e(TAG, "Advertise failed : " + errorCode);
    }
});
```

stopAdvertising Method :

```
public void stopAdvertising(){

        Log.d(TAG, "stoping advertising ..." );
        advertiser.stopAdvertising(new AdvertiseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onStopSuccess" );
                super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onStopFailed" + errorCode );
                super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
            }
        });
        advertiser = null;
    }
```

But when i call the stopAdvertising method the advertising doesn't stop, i don't no if it can help but, when i call my method stopAdvertising i get :

```
D/ContentValues: stoping advertising ...
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeAdvertiser: wrapper is null
```

Comment: Take out the 'advertiser = null'. That prevents the callbacks from happening

Comment: even without, the callback isn't happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to my own question :**

The problem was that the callback for stopAdvertising and startAdvertising must be the same object as said by google doc :

```
* Stop Bluetooth LE advertising. The {@code callback} must be the same one use in
* {@link BluetoothLeAdvertiser#startAdvertising}.
```

(the callback is used to identify the instance of advertise by google's sdk)

Using the same callback for both worked for me